# problem in discord bot (on_voice_state_update) (member aruguement)

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_voice_state_update(self, channel, before, after, member):
        channel = self.bot.get_channel([CHANNEL-ID])
        member = VoiceChannel.members
        if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
                await channel.send(f'{member} JOINED {after.channel}')
```

Error:    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_voice_state_update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'

there is no problem if :

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_voice_state_update(self, channel, before, after):
        channel = self.bot.get_channel([CHANNEL-ID])
        if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
                await channel.send(f'someone JOINED {after.channel}')
```

so how do I get the name of the member who join the voice channel

Comment: I think the docs are pretty clear about what arguments [`on_voice_state_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update) takes...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're getting the error because the event function is supposed to have exactly three (excluding self) parameters. These parameters are `member`, `before` and `after`.

To answer your question: You get the member that joined using your first positional argument which you have currently called `channel`. To get the channel, you can use `before.channel` or `after.channel` respectively. Note that a channel might be `None` to indicate joining/leaving instead of just switching channels.

Also see the official doc on this event: [discord.on_voice_state_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=voice_state_update#discord.on_voice_state_update)

> `discord.on_voice_state_update(member, before, after)`
>
> Called when a [Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=voice_state_update#discord.Member) changes their [VoiceState](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=voice_state_update#discord.VoiceState).
> The following, but not limited to, examples illustrate when this event is called:
>
> - A member joins a voice channel.
> - A member leaves a voice channel.
> - A member is muted or deafened by their own accord.
> - A member is muted or deafened by a guild administrator.
>
> This requires [Intents.voice_states](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=voice_state_update#discord.Intents.voice_states) to be enabled.
>
> Parameters
>
> - `member` ([Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=voice_state_update#discord.Member)) – The member whose voice states changed.
> - `before` ([VoiceState](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=voice_state_update#discord.VoiceState)) – The voice state prior to the changes.
> - `after` ([VoiceState](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=voice_state_update#discord.VoiceState)) – The voice state after the changes.